Connect to a printer scanner with JAVA
I am trying to develop a solution that allows me to connect to a printer, and obtain a scan of a document through the printer's scanner. The only problem is that when I want to access printers connected by network or shared resources, I cannot connect directly. To be able to do this I used several libraries to try, such as Twain, Morena, and one from mmscomputing, but I couldn't get anywhere, I could only get an implementation with Morena, but if the PC was connected by USB to the printer. I don't know if anyone could help me with an explanation, or a tool that would allow me to implement this more easily. Thank you very much in advance, I have attached the code that I used with Morena and it works but only via USB.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageConsumer;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;

import SK.gnome.morena.Morena;
import SK.gnome.morena.MorenaImage;
import SK.gnome.morena.MorenaSource;
import SK.gnome.twain.TwainSource;
import SK.gnome.twain.TwainSource.Frame;


public class ScannerApp extends JApplet 
{ private static class MainPanel extends JPanel
  { private JTextField status = new JTextField();
    private ImagePanel selected=null;
    private SaveImageAction saveImageAction;
    private UploadImageAction uploadImageAction;
    private MouseListener mouseListener=new MouseListener();
    private boolean hasServer=false;
    private URL documentBase=null;

    private class RemoveAllAction extends AbstractAction implements Runnable
    { RemoveAllAction()
      { super("remove all");
      }
    
      public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      { new Thread(this).start();
      }

      public synchronized void run()
      { removeAll();
        select(null);
        repaint();
      }
    }

    private class AcquireImageAction extends AbstractAction implements Runnable
    { AcquireImageAction()
      { super("acquire image");
      }
    
      public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      { new Thread(this).start();
      }

      public synchronized void run()
      { try
        { status.setText("Working ...");
          MorenaSource source=Morena.selectSource(MainPanel.this);
          if (source!=null)
          { source.setColorMode();
            source.setResolution(100);
            while (true)
            { MorenaImage morenaImage=new MorenaImage(source);
              int imageStatus=morenaImage.getStatus();
              if (imageStatus==ImageConsumer.STATICIMAGEDONE)
              { int imageWidth=morenaImage.getWidth();
                int imageHeight=morenaImage.getHeight();
                int imagePixelSize=morenaImage.getPixelSize();
                ImagePanel image=new ImagePanel(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(morenaImage));
                MainPanel.this.add(image);
                select(image);
                int size=(int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(getComponentCount()));
                setLayout(new GridLayout(size, size));
                
                if (TwainSource.class.isInstance(source))
                {
                  Frame frame=((TwainSource)source).getFrame();
                  status.setText("Done - actual image frame is ["+Math.round(100*frame.left)/100.0+", "+Math.round(100*frame.top)/100.0+"] - ["+Math.round(100*frame.right)/100.0+", "+Math.round(100*frame.bottom)/100.0+"] ...");
                }
                else
                  status.setText("Done - actual image size is "+imageWidth+" x "+imageHeight+" x "+imagePixelSize+" ...");
                validate();
                if (TwainSource.class.isInstance(source) && ((TwainSource)source).hasMoreImages())
                  continue;
              }
              else if (imageStatus==ImageConsumer.IMAGEABORTED)
                status.setText("Aborted, try again ...");
              else if (imageStatus==ImageConsumer.IMAGEERROR)
                status.setText("Failed, try again ...");
              break;
            }
          }
          else
            status.setText("Failed, try again ...");
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodError error)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainPanel.this, "Previous version of Morena is installed in "+System.getProperty("java.home")+".\nYou have to remove it first.\nClick OK to terminate browser.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (Throwable exception)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainPanel.this, exception.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          exception.printStackTrace();
          status.setText("Failed, try again ...");
        }
        finally
        { try
          { Morena.close();
          }
          catch (Exception exception)
          { exception.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    private class SaveImageAction extends AbstractAction implements Runnable
    { private class Filter extends FileFilter
      { String type;
        
        Filter(String type)
        { this.type=type;
        }
        
        public boolean accept(File file)
        { return file.getName().endsWith(type);
        }

        public String getDescription()
        { return type+" Files";
        } 
      }

      SaveImageAction()
      { super("save to file");
      }
    
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      { new Thread(this).start();
      }

      public synchronized void run()
      { try
        { status.setText("Working ...");
          Image image=selected.getImage();
          BufferedImage bufferedImage=new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
          bufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
          JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
//        Java 1.6 introduced a comfortable ImageIO.getWriterFileSuffixes() method.
          String e[] = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();
          for (int i=0; i<e.length; i++)
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new Filter(e[i]));
          int result=chooser.showSaveDialog(MainPanel.this);
          if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
          { String ext=chooser.getFileFilter().getDescription();
            ext=ext.substring(0, ext.indexOf(' ')).toLowerCase();
            File file=chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String name=file.getName();
            if (!name.endsWith(ext))
              file=new File(file.getParentFile(), name+"."+ext);
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, ext, file);
          }
        }
        catch (Throwable exception)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainPanel.this, exception.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          exception.printStackTrace();
          status.setText("Failed, try again ...");
        }
      }

      public boolean isEnabled()
      { return selected != null;
      }
    }

    private class UploadImageAction extends AbstractAction implements Runnable
    { UploadImageAction()
      { super("upload to server");
      }
    
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      { new Thread(this).start();
      }

      public synchronized void run()
      { try
        { status.setText("Working ...");
          Image image=selected.getImage();
          ByteArrayOutputStream tmp=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          BufferedImage bufferedImage=new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
          bufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
          ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", tmp);
          tmp.close();
          int contentLength=tmp.size();
          if (contentLength>1024*1024)
            throw new Exception("Image is too big to upload");
          URL uploadURL=new URL(documentBase, "upload.php");
          HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)uploadURL.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setUseCaches(false);
          connection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
          connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "img/jpeg");
          connection.setRequestProperty("content-length", String.valueOf(contentLength));
          OutputStream out=connection.getOutputStream();
          out.write(tmp.toByteArray());
          out.close();
          InputStream in=connection.getInputStream();
          int c;
          while ((c=in.read())!=-1)
            System.err.write(c);
          in.close();
          URL imageURL=new URL(documentBase, connection.getHeaderField("file-name"));
          status.setText("Done - image is uploaded to "+imageURL+" (for at least 5 minutes) ...");
        }
        catch (Throwable exception)
        { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainPanel.this, exception.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          exception.printStackTrace();
          status.setText("Failed, try again ...");
        }
      }

      public boolean isEnabled()
      { return hasServer && selected != null;
      }
    }

    private class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    { public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
      { select((ImagePanel)event.getComponent());
      } 
    }
    
    private class ImagePanel extends JPanel
    { private Image image;
      int imageWidth;
      int imageHeight;
      
      ImagePanel(Image image)
      { this.image=image;
        imageWidth=image.getWidth(null);
        imageHeight=image.getHeight(null);
        addMouseListener(mouseListener);
      }
      
      public Image getImage()
      { return image;
      }
      
      public void paint(Graphics g)
      { super.paint(g);
        int panelWidth=getWidth()-6;
        int panelHeight=getHeight()-6;
        double horizontalRatio=(double)panelWidth/imageWidth;
        double verticalRatio=(double)panelHeight/imageHeight;
        if (horizontalRatio>verticalRatio)
          g.drawImage(image, (int)(panelWidth-imageWidth*verticalRatio)/2+3, 3, (int)(imageWidth*verticalRatio), (int)(imageHeight*verticalRatio), this);
        else
          g.drawImage(image, 3, 3, (int)(imageWidth*horizontalRatio), (int)(imageHeight*horizontalRatio), this);
      }

    }
    
    private class ToolBar extends JToolBar
    { ToolBar()
      { add(new RemoveAllAction());
        addSeparator();
        add(new AcquireImageAction());
        addSeparator();
        add(saveImageAction=new SaveImageAction());
        saveImageAction.setEnabled(false);
        addSeparator();
        add(uploadImageAction=new UploadImageAction());
        uploadImageAction.setEnabled(false);
        setMargin(new Insets(4, 2, 2, 2));
      }
    }
    
    private class StatusBar extends JToolBar
    { StatusBar()
      { add(status);
        status.setText("Ready ...");
      }
    }
    
    void select(ImagePanel image)
    { if(selected != null)
      selected.setBorder(null);
      selected = image;
      if(selected != null)
      {
        selected.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 1));
        saveImageAction.setEnabled(true);
        uploadImageAction.setEnabled(hasServer);
      } else
      {
        saveImageAction.setEnabled(false);
        uploadImageAction.setEnabled(false);
      }
    }
    
    MainPanel(Container container, URL documentBase)
    { this.documentBase=documentBase;
      status.setEditable(false);
      hasServer=documentBase!=null && documentBase.getProtocol().indexOf("http")!=-1;
      container.add(new ToolBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      container.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      container.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    }
  }
  
  public void init()
  { new MainPanel(getContentPane(), getDocumentBase());
  }
  
  public static void main(String args[])
  { JFrame frame=new JFrame("Morena Studio");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    new MainPanel(frame.getContentPane(), null);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

Edit: If it can be a free implementation it would be incredible
Morena: https://www.gnome.sk/Morena/morena.html
Ejemplos
I tried many implementations, such as those already mentioned, WIA, TWAIN, SANE, and none of them solved it for me for free and with printers connected by network

Anything that's using applets is outdated. Have you looked at this?

Unfortunately I need to carry out an implementation like this. But I tried everything and there is not much documentation, almost nothing, I had seen that publication, and from there I had tried some alternatives. The only drawback, as I mentioned, is that there is not much documentation, and there are several that require payment. Thank you very much for your contribution as well!

If you know more documentation or a simple implementation to try, and functional with printers connected by network, I will be very grateful haha
